# Perl reorder an array of hashes based on content

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Have an array of hashes, I want to be able to reorder them, moving the first entry I find that matches a criteria to be the first entry in the array.

using [List::Utils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) first method I can identify what I want to be the first entry in the array. How can I make the found entry the first element in the AoH?

@Borodin

An example of what the data looks like:

```
CAT1 => 'Foo', CAT2 => 'BAR', TITLE='test1',
CAT1 => 'BAZ', CAT2 => 'BAR', TITLE='test2',
.....
```

It has many entries. I wish to find the first entry (there could be more than one) where CAT1=BAZ and CAT2=BAR and move it to be the first item in the AoH.

Comment: Can you please add the code you've written with List::Utils?

Comment: *"moving the first entry I find that matches a criteria to be the first entry in the array"* Are you talking about *only ever* moving one hash to the top? Or do you really want to sort an array of hashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without realistic sample data it is hard to help.

You may sort the values of a list according to any criterion that is computable using Perl's [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) operator, which takes an expression or a block as its second parameter

The library [`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy) provides operators `sort_by` etc. that will probably provide a speed advantage if the sort criterion is a complex one

---

This sets up the data you've given and dumps it using [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump)

Then I've used `first_index` from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils), which finds the index of the first element of the array that conforms to your criteria

```
$_->{CAT1} eq 'BAZ' and $_->{CAT2} eq 'BAR'
```

And then an `unshift` together with a `splice` removes that element and puts it at the front of the array. There's a check that `$i` isn't zero to avoid moving an item that's already at the start of the array

Finally another call to `dd` shows that the matching item has been moved

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::MoreUtils 'first_index';
use Data::Dump;

my @data = (
    {
        CAT1  => 'Foo',
        CAT2  => 'BAR',
        TITLE => 'test1',
    },
    {
        CAT1  => 'BAZ',
        CAT2  => 'BAR',
        TITLE => 'test2',
    }
);

dd \@data;

my $i = first_index {
    $_->{CAT1} eq 'BAZ' and $_->{CAT2} eq 'BAR'
} @data;

die if $i < 0;
unshift @data, splice @data, $i, 1 unless $i == 0;

dd \@data;
```

#### output

```
[
  { CAT1 => "Foo", CAT2 => "BAR", TITLE => "test1" },
  { CAT1 => "BAZ", CAT2 => "BAR", TITLE => "test2" },
]
[
  { CAT1 => "BAZ", CAT2 => "BAR", TITLE => "test2" },
  { CAT1 => "Foo", CAT2 => "BAR", TITLE => "test1" },
]
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To move the first matching entry to the start:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( first_index );

my $i = first_index { matches($_) } @aoh;
unshift @aoh, splice(@aoh, $i, 1);
```

To move all matching entries to the start:

```
use sort 'stable';
@aoh = 
   sort {
      my $a_matches = matches($a);
      my $b_matches = matches($b);
      ( $a_matches ? 0 : 1 ) <=> ( $b_matches ? 0 : 1 )
   } 
      @aoh;
```

Comment: I get `can't call method "matches" on unblessed reference`. Sorry, I'm not getting this.

Comment: You didn't specify the criteria to matches, so I couldn't write `matches` for you. It's up to you to write the code to check if an element matches your criteria! /// According to your update, it's `sub matches { my ($h) = @_; $h->{CAT1} eq 'BAZ' && $h->{CAT2} eq 'BAR' }`, but doens't really have anything to do with the question.

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche: This solution uses a function `matches` that you are supposed to write yourself. It's a misnomer because it must transform a single element of the list to a value that you want to use for comparison in the sort